# In React, is it an antipattern if a map is done every rerender?

Tags: reactjs

For example, if I have the main component and it uses a `useEffect()` to fetch data from the server, and then uses a `GalleyViewer` to display the images in a 3 x 3 grid and it can allow the user to go to next page and prev page.

So I would do a:

```
  <GalleryViewer 
    imageURLs={data.items.map(e => e.details.url)}
    ...
  />
```

However, since every re-render, this `map()` is going to be run once.

Is it true that if the loop is, say, merely 50, then it is not a big concern.  But what if it is a big number, such as 500 or 1000, then it may not be so ideal.

Also, since `map()` creates a new array each time, that means `GalleryViewer` will be re-rendered also, even though it doesn't need to.

But what if I don't feel any sluggish UI at all on my local development machine? Is it a best practice to optimize it?  What if on my MacBook Air M2, it feels fast, but what about some users who may be using a 4 year old low end PC that the tech department gave them at work?

I can think of using `useEffect()` to set a state `imageURLs` whenever the `data` changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      setImageURLs(data.items.map(e => e.details.url))
    },
    [data]
  );
```

or use a `useMemo` to cache an `imageURLs`, but these also seem to increase the coupling of the code: to use `GalleryViewer`, the `useEffect` is needed, and the programmer need to constantly monitor if the dependency array needs to be modified due to some other parts of the code being changed.

Another way if we can refactor `GalleryViewer`:

```
  const urlSelector = useCallback(
    e => e.details.url,
    []
  );
  
  return ( ...

    <GalleryViewer 
      items={data.items}
      urlSelector={urlSelector}
      ...
    />
```

so if `data.items` doesn't change, there is no re-rendering of `GalleryViewer`. The `urlSelector` function is run only for 9 times for that 3 x 3 grid, so it won't be going through the whole array.

Come to think about it, if Redux is being used, then since Redux would construct a new value every time (so that it is immutable), that means `data` will be a new value and it will cause the `useEffect` or `useMemo` to run, so it doesn't help in this case?

So is using `map()` in the original code an antipattern in React and what is a best practice?

Comment: I'd say your solution is more flexible to future change, such as if the information in `data.items` has usages outside of the `e.details.url` (per element). Then you wouldn't have to change the `state` that is held, only the output of it (or perhaps not even changing the output, just re-using what exists elsewhere). Beware premature optimization, build an application which is readible, maintainable, and well-designed. After that, profile it and find the real bottlenecks.

Comment: right... I usually won't do premature optimization. Just that for example if I am in an interview, should I write it this way or start with the `useEffect` or `useMemo` because if I don't, I worry that the interviewers may think, "ok... the candidate writes ok React code but it is not the idiomatic, speedy code that we'd expect from an experienced React programmer"

Comment: I'd say screw it - write what works, optimize later. Don't be blatantly unperformant, but nonobvious things aren't of huge import compared to non-technical skills in an interview imo (how well you learn and work with a team, for instance). Every company has different standards, it's a matter of picking them up and running with them.

Comment: Why don't you use `useMemo`?

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is it’s fine. Even for large arrays you would probably feel the performance issue somewhere else (like when you’re fetching the data) before you would have an issue because of the map.

React does the work to handle this on the virtual DOM (and avoids making unnecessary changes to the DOM), so I don’t think it will amount to much of a performance hit.

I would say move forward with the first way you have written it and refactor later if you have a problem.

Comment: you mean "virtual DOM"?

Comment: yeah, sometimes I feel uneasy because React is like Lisp being functional programming and declarative: you always know the value of something, but you don't know the cost of it

Comment: Updated the comment to clarify the distinction between the virtual DOM and DOM. Unfortunately, you’re mostly going to end up with opinions on a question like this. I generally agree with Rogue’s comment, “write what works, optimize later.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bad pattern. The data is best sent as a component variable:

```
<GalleryViewer imageURLs={imageURLs} />
```

This variable is taken from redux and when it is updated the component is re-rendered. We don't even need useEffect , we just output data:

```
return ({imageURLs.map((url) => '<img href='+url+'>')})
```

And this will be the best solution. It is necessary to follow the principle of SOLID architecture, if you do not know, you need to read about it